# Incremental Learning using MAXSMT

Tags: z3, smt, optimathsat

Can we use the previous solution of a MaxSMT solver (optimize) in an incremental way in z3? Also, Is there any way to print out the soft assertions on the optimizer?

Comment: This is possible in OptiMathSAT via API,, and I guess that for z3 it is the same. Evaluate each soft-clause on the optimal model and then *"use it"*. -- This is a rather generic answer, hence I leave it as a comment. Can you refine the question a little bit so as to better define its scope and understand the problem at hand?

Comment: For instance, If I start with a small set of soft constraints, check model, then add another small set of soft constraints and repeat this process until some stopping criteria. My question is, Is is better than enforcing all the soft constraints together?

Comment: Are you learning previous soft constraints as hard? (or a subset of them) Are new soft-constraints part of the same MaxSMT goal? (same ID)

Comment: I don't know what you mean "previous soft constraints as hard". Yes new soft constraints are a part of the same goal. There are no hard constraint in the model.

Comment: A soft constraint becomes hard if the value it had in the previous optimal solution is fixed with an assertion. In your application, are soft-constraints completely independent, or can new soft-constraints with higher weight result in a different optimal assignment over earlier soft-constraints?

Comment: In my problem (I haven't formulated it yet), we don't want to make the soft assertions as hard constraints. Idea is to use the previous solution to optimize for the new set of soft constraints and so on, until you can't. Is it feasible?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The soft constraints are not completely independent. New soft-constraints can result in a different optimal assignment over earlier soft-constraints (or maybe even some of the earlier soft constraints are not satisfied anymore). in the second iteration, does it optimize for the soft-constraints of both iterations or just the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **YES** if you are asking whether it is *technically* possible to run either `z3` or `OptiMathSAT` *incrementally* with a MaxSMT problem. *(Use the API).*

All soft-clauses with the same `id` *--at the moment in which one performs a `check-sat`--* are considered part of the same MaxSMT goal. In essence, the OMT solver evaluates the relevant set of soft-clauses of a MaxSMT goal lazily. This holds for both `z3` and `OptiMathSAT`.

> An optimal solution found at an early stage may be *far away* from the optimal solution of later stages of the iterative process.

When dealing with a MaxSMT problem, the ability of an OMT solver to reuse
learned clauses across *incremental* calls may depend on the optimization algorithm that is being used.

I see two possible cases:

- One is using a **core-based** MaxSMT engine. In this case, exploring formulations of the problem with an increasing level of complexity may help identifying a *tractable* sub-set of the original problem. However, notice that lemmas involving soft-constraints learned at previous iterations may not be useful at later stages *(Actually, the OMT solver is going to discard all of these clauses and re-compute them if necessary)*.
- One is using a **sat-based** MaxSMT engine. In this case, it is not clear to me the benefit of splitting the problem into smaller chunks, other than focusing the search over particular groups of *(?possibly related?)* soft-clauses. The OMT solver could be given all soft-constraints at once, together with a hard timeout, and it would still be able to yield a partial optimal solution when the alarm fires. *(T-Lemmas involving the cost function are not going to be useful across incremental calls because the cost function changes. In the best scenario, the OMT solvers discards them. In the worst scenario, these T-Lemmas remain in the environment and clutter the search without altering the solution).*

  I admit that it is a bit hard to predict the performance of the OMT solver because of the overhead that is introduced with either approach. On the one hand, we have the overhead of *incremental* calls and the fact that the optimization process is restarted from scratch multiple times. On the other hand, we have the overhead of performing BCP over a much larger set of soft-clauses. I guess that the balance turns in favor of the *incremental* approach for sufficiently large sets of soft-clauses. *[This would be an interesting subject of investigation, I would love to read a paper about it!]*

Comment: Fantastic answer as usual Patrick! That paper you're referring to: You'll have to write it!